# How to fetch large API data in react and send back request to server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Let me explain what I want to achieve?

- This is the fetched data to get the image links and save it to **setImageLinkData** state which is over 100,000 links [image]
- Since, I want to do something after the **imageLinkData** state is updated so, I use the useEffect hook to do it

```
const [ imageLinkData, setImageLinkData ] = useState([]);
const [ imageLink, setImageLink ] = useState([]);
const [ additionalImageLink, setAdditionalImageLink ] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        const checkLink = async () => {
            if (imageLinkData.length > 0) {
                checkMainImage(imageLinkData, (resultImg) => setImageLink(resultImg)); // test main image link
                checkAdditionalImage(imageLinkData, (resultImg) => setAdditionalImageLink(resultImg)); // test additional image link
                const response = await getSuggList();
            }
        }
        checkLink();
    }, [imageLinkData])
```

- I tested the link if the image exists with the two function one for **imageLink** and another for **additionalImageLink**
- After I test the link I get validated links from the callback function and save it to **setImageLink** and **setAdditionalImageLink** state respectively.

```
 const checkMainImage = (linkArray, callback) => {
        linkArray.map(element => {
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = element.imageLink;
            img.onload = () => {
                setImageLink(element.imageLink);
                callback(element.imageLink);
            };
            img.onerror = () => {
                callback('donot');
            };
        });
    }
```

```
const checkAdditionalImage = (linkArray, callback) => {
        linkArray.map(element => {
            element.additionalImageLink.map(addImage => {
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = addImage;
                img.onload = () => {
                    return callback(addImage);
                };
                img.onerror = () => {
                    return callback('donot');
                };
            })
        });
    }
```

- So, what happening in my code next is when I try to access the **imageLink** state(not from the json data) and **additionalImageLink** state(not from the json data) I only get one or two value

```
useEffect(() => {
        // if (imageLink.length > 0 || additionalImageLink.length > 0)
            console.log(imageLink);
    }, [imageLink])
```

- The result

[image]

Comment: _"save it to setImageLink"_... shouldn't you be saving it to `setImageLinkData`? This is very confusing without seeing your data retrieval code and what happens to the result. You're also missing details for `checkMainImage`

Comment: Sorry Phil and u r right. I jst edited the post again would u mind helping me this out?

Answer (score 0):

```
checkMainImage(imageLinkData, (resultImg) => setImageLink(resultImg)); // test main image link
checkAdditionalImage(imageLinkData, (resultImg) => setAdditionalImageLink(resultImg)); // test additional image link
```

In this `setImageLink(resultImg)` and `setAdditionalImageLink(resultImg)`, you are setting only the last value that is available in the json data.

Shouldn't it be pushing the value to the `imageLink` and `additionalImageLink` array?

Like `setImageLink([...imageLink, resultImg])`?